# Groupby and number the groups

Tags: python, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
ID status     datetime 
2.  Complete. 28.01.2019 16:09:08
3.  Complete. 28.01.2019 13:08:08
4.  New.      29.01.2019 16:09:08
4.  Amend.    23.01.2019 15:09:08
5.  New.      21.01.2019 19:09:08
6.  New.      21.01.2019 16:09:08
7.  New.      20.01.2019 16:09:08
7.  Amend.    23.01.2019 09:09:08
7.  Amend.    23.01.2019 09:12:08
7.  Complete. 24.01.2019 13:09:08
```

I want to group the data by it's ID and sorted out by its timestamp. I then want to be able to drop any ID group where the status does not involves an Amend. For Example in this case, I only groups with ID : 4 and 7 would remain.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I cannot seem to find a code where I filter out groups who's status do not contain 'Amend'

Comment: If you show what you have tried, maybe someone can tell you why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not pretty sure if it helps you but you can use pandas to group your data by `ID`

and then apply a filter on the `status` column of each group to check if it matches your condition.

Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[    ["2.",  "Complete.", "28.01.2019 16:09:08"],
              ["3.",  "Complete.", "28.01.2019 13:08:08"],
              ["4.",  "New.",      "29.01.2019 16:09:08"],
              ["4.",  "Amend.",    "23.01.2019 15:09:08"],
              ["5.",  "New.",      "21.01.2019 19:09:08"],
              ["6.",  "New.",      "21.01.2019 16:09:08"],
              ["7.",  "New.",      "20.01.2019 16:09:08"],
              ["7.",  "Amend.",    "23.01.2019 09:09:08"],
              ["7.",  "Amend.",    "23.01.2019 09:12:08"],
              ["7.",  "Complete.", "24.01.2019 13:09:08"]
    ],
    columns=["ID", "status", "datetime"]
)
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: not x.status.str.contains('Amend').any())
```

It gives you something like this

```py
ID
2.     True
3.     True
4.    False
5.     True
6.     True
7.    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you! this works perfect. A follow up: how would I calculate the difference between the dates within each group. This is to see if the Amend status within each group is day or more?

Comment: @KanikaKaur you can convert the datetime column into `DateTime` format using the `pd.to_datetime` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ask it directly to pandas: groupby ID, and test where status `Amend.` is in the group:

```
result = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x if 'Amend.' in x['status'].values else None).dropna()
```

It gives as expected:

```
    ID     status             datetime
2  4.0       New.  29.01.2019 16:09:08
3  4.0     Amend.  23.01.2019 15:09:08
6  7.0       New.  20.01.2019 16:09:08
7  7.0     Amend.  23.01.2019 09:09:08
8  7.0     Amend.  23.01.2019 09:12:08
9  7.0  Complete.  24.01.2019 13:09:08
```

Comment: Thank you! this does work. However, the output then excludes any status in the group that Is New or complete.

Comment: @KanikaKaur ??? I can see a status `New.` in the first line of `result`. I am afraid I cannot understand what you are asking here...